# Writing Curl POST in R: uploading an image to a website

Tags: r, image, curl, post

I am trying to upload an image to a website. Below is the successful curl function:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://xxxxx?laboratoryResultVisibleId=LR-116807&assayAttribute=Trace&onBehalfOf=minnie' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic U1JWR0JMLUdEQklPTDpQZjgyNTE5Mw==' \
--form 'imageFile=@/C:/Users/minnie/Downloads/plot.png'
```

I am writing my R code as follows:

```
username <- "minnie"
url <- "http://xxxxx"
auth <- authenticate(user='abc', password='xyz', type="basic")
header <- list(username)
names(header) <- "X-On-Behalf-Of"

filepath <- "C:/Users/minnie/Downloads/plot.png"

post_zip <- httr::POST(
  url = url,
  auth,
  body = list(
              laboratoryResultVisibleId = 'LR-116807',
              assayAttribute = 'Trace',
              file = httr::upload_file(filepath), 
              userid = username
              ),
  httr::add_headers("Content-Type"="multipart/form-data")
)

post_zip
content(post_zip, "text")
```

and I got the following feedback:

```
Response [http://xxxxx]
  Date: 2020-11-18 22:30
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
  Size: 43 B

> content(post_zip, "text")
[1] "{\"success\":false,\"message\":\"No File found\"}"
```

It seems that no file has been found. Any clue? Thank you so much for your help :-)

Comment: Have you made sure this is true file.exists() with full path to file in parens

Comment: > file.exists("plot.png") 
[1] TRUE

Comment: Wait, why not take the easy route and just issue the successful curl command? If in an Rmarkdown file just make the code chunk a bash chunk ?

Comment: I am trying to connect R shiny to a website, and thus, it must be R code. It is kind of automation pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resides in the file path. We should use the file.path () function in R to let the server know it is a file path, rather than a character string.

```
filepath <- file.path(getwd(), "plot.png")

post_zip <- httr::POST(
  url = url,
  auth,
  body = list(
              laboratoryResultVisibleId = 'LR-116807',
              assayAttribute = 'Trace',
              imageFile = httr::upload_file(filepath), 
              userid = username
              ),
  httr::add_headers("Content-Type"="multipart/form-data")
)

post_zip
content(post_zip, "text")
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this has something to do with http vs https, can you try changing to https?

Comment: It should be 'http'. I have confirmed.